# LibGDX Player only faces left and movement isn't animated

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working on a game in LibGDX and both my players direction and walking animation won't change. He can walk up, down, left, and right, but only faces left no matter what direction he's walking.

```
public class WorldController {

enum KeyBinds {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, JUMP, FIRE
}

private World world;
private Player p;

static Map<KeyBinds, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<WorldController.KeyBinds, Boolean>();
static {
    keys.put(KeyBinds.LEFT, false);
    keys.put(KeyBinds.RIGHT, false);
    keys.put(KeyBinds.UP, false);
    keys.put(KeyBinds.DOWN, false);
    keys.put(KeyBinds.JUMP, false);
    keys.put(KeyBinds.FIRE, false);
};

public WorldController(World world) {
    this.world = world;
    this.p = world.getPlayer();
}

// ** Key presses and touches **************** //

public void leftPressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.LEFT, true));
}

public void rightPressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.RIGHT, true));
}

public void upPressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.UP, true));
}

public void downPressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.DOWN, true));
}

public void jumpPressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.JUMP, true));
}

public void firePressed() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.FIRE, false));
}

public void leftReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.LEFT, false));
}

public void rightReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.RIGHT, false));
}

public void upReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.UP, false));
}

public void downReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.DOWN, false));
}

public void jumpReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.JUMP, false));
}

public void fireReleased() {
    keys.get(keys.put(KeyBinds.FIRE, false));
}

/** The main update method **/
public void update(float delta) {
    processInput();
    p.update(delta);
}

/** Change player's state and parameters based on input controls **/
private void processInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
        // left is pressed

        //p.setFacingLeft(true);
        p.setState(State.WALKING);
        p.getVelocity().x = -Player.SPEED;
        p.getVelocity().y = 0;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        // right is pressed

        //p.setFacingRight(true);
        p.setState(State.WALKING);
        p.getVelocity().x = Player.SPEED;
        p.getVelocity().y = 0;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
        // up is pressed

        //p.setFacingUp(true);
        p.setState(State.WALKING);
        p.getVelocity().y = Player.SPEED;
        p.getVelocity().x = 0;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
        // down is pressed

        //p.setFacingDown(true);
        p.setState(State.WALKING);
        p.getVelocity().y = -Player.SPEED;
        p.getVelocity().x = 0;
    }
    // need to check if both or none direction are pressed, then player is idle
//      if ((keys.get(Keys.LEFT) && keys.get(Keys.RIGHT)) ||
//              (!keys.get(Keys.LEFT) && !(keys.get(Keys.RIGHT)))) {
//          p.setState(State.IDLE);
//          // acceleration is 0 on the x
//          p.getAcceleration().x = 0;
//          // horizontal speed is 0
//          p.getVelocity().x = 0;
//      }
}
}





public class WorldRenderer {

private static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 10f;
private static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 7f;


    private World world;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    /** for debug rendering **/
    ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private boolean debug = false;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float ppuX;
    private float ppuY;

    private static final float RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION = 0.06f;

    /** Textures **/
    private TextureRegion pIdleLeft;
    private TextureRegion pIdleRight;
    private TextureRegion pIdleUp;
    private TextureRegion pIdleDown;
    private TextureRegion blockTexture;
    private TextureRegion pFrame;

    /** Animations **/
    private Animation walkLeftAnimation;
    private Animation walkRightAnimation;
    private Animation walkUpAnimation;
    private Animation walkDownAnimation;

    private void loadTextures() {
        TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images/textures/textures.pack"));
        pIdleLeft = atlas.findRegion("Left1");
        pIdleRight = new TextureRegion(pIdleLeft);
        pIdleRight.flip(true, false);
        pIdleUp = atlas.findRegion("Back1");
        pIdleDown = atlas.findRegion("Front1");
        blockTexture = atlas.findRegion("stone");

        //Walking Left Animation
        TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[2];

        walkLeftFrames[0] = atlas.findRegion("Left1");
        walkLeftFrames[1] = atlas.findRegion("Left2");

        walkLeftAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION, walkLeftFrames);

        //Walking Right Animation
        TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[2];

        walkRightFrames[0] = new TextureRegion(walkLeftFrames[0]);
        walkRightFrames[0].flip(true, false);

        walkRightFrames[1] = new TextureRegion(walkLeftFrames[1]);
        walkRightFrames[1].flip(true, false);

        walkRightAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION, walkRightFrames);

        //Walking Up Animation
        TextureRegion[] walkUpFrames = new TextureRegion[2];

        walkUpFrames[0] = atlas.findRegion("Back1");
        walkUpFrames[1] = atlas.findRegion("Back2");

        walkUpAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION, walkUpFrames);

        //Walking Down Animation
        TextureRegion[] walkDownFrames = new TextureRegion[2];

        walkLeftFrames[0] = atlas.findRegion("Front1");
        walkLeftFrames[1] = atlas.findRegion("Front2");

        walkDownAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION, walkDownFrames);
    }

    public void drawPlayer() {
        Player p = world.getPlayer();
        if(p.getState().equals(State.IDLE)) {
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) pFrame = pIdleLeft;
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) pFrame = pIdleRight;
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) pFrame = pIdleUp;
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) pFrame = pIdleDown;
        }

        if(p.getState().equals(State.WALKING)) {
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(p.getStateTime(), true);
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) walkRightAnimation.getKeyFrame(p.getStateTime(), true);
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) walkUpAnimation.getKeyFrame(p.getStateTime(), true);
            else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) walkDownAnimation.getKeyFrame(p.getStateTime(), true);
        }

        spriteBatch.draw(pFrame, p.getXPosition() * ppuX, p.getYPosition() * ppuY, Player.SIZE * ppuX, Player.SIZE * ppuY);
    }

    public void setSize(int w, int h){
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        ppuX = (float)width / CAMERA_WIDTH;
        ppuY = (float)height / CAMERA_HEIGHT;

    }

    public WorldRenderer(World world, boolean debug) {
        this.world = world;
        this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        this.cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
        this.cam.update();
        this.debug = debug;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        loadTextures();
    }

    public void render(){
        spriteBatch.begin();
            drawBlocks();
            drawPlayer();
        spriteBatch.end();
        if(debug){
            drawDebug();
        }
    }

    public void drawBlocks(){
        for(Block block : world.getBlocks()){
            spriteBatch.draw(blockTexture, block.getXPosition() * ppuX, block.getYPosition() * ppuY, Block.getSize() * ppuX, Block.getSize() * ppuY );
        }
    }

    public void drawDebug() {
        // render blocks
        debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        for (Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
            Rectangle rect = block.getBounds();
            float x1 = block.getXPosition() + rect.x;
            float y1 = block.getYPosition() + rect.y;
            debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
            debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
        }
    // render Player
    Player p = world.getPlayer();
    Rectangle rect = p.getBounds();
    float x1 = p.getXPosition() + rect.x;
    float y1 = p.getYPosition() + rect.y;
    debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
    debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
    debugRenderer.end();
}
}



public class Player {

public enum State{
    IDLE, WALKING, JUMPING, DYING
}

public static final float SPEED = 4f; //units per second
public static final float SIZE = 0.5f; //half a unit
float stateTime = 0;

Vector2 position = new Vector2();
Vector2 acceleration = new Vector2();
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
State state = State.IDLE;

boolean facingLeft;
boolean facingRight;
boolean facingUp;
boolean facingDown;

public Player(Vector2 position){
    this.position = position;
    this.bounds.height = SIZE;
    this.bounds.width = SIZE;
}

public void setFacingLeft(boolean facingLeft) {
    this.facingLeft = facingLeft;
}

public void setFacingRight(boolean facingRight) {
    this.facingRight = facingRight;
}

public void setFacingUp(boolean facingUp) {
    this.facingUp = facingUp;
}

public void setFacingDown(boolean facingDown) {
    this.facingDown = facingDown;
}

public Vector2 getAcceleration() {
    return acceleration;
}

public Vector2 getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
}

public void setState(State newState){
    this.state = newState;
}

public void update(float delta){
    stateTime += delta;
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}

public Object getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public float getXPosition(){
    return this.position.x;
}

public float getYPosition(){
    return this.position.y;
}

public Object getState() {
    return state;
}

public float getStateTime() {
    return stateTime;
}
}
```

Sorry for all the code but I don't know where the problem is and didn't want to leave out anything relevant. I'm sure it's a silly mistake but I've been starring at it for a long time.

Also, I made an effort to put each class in it's own code block but it wasn't working out, I'm new to stackoverflow. Thanks to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: The player's `facingLeft` field is initialized to `true`. It doesn't look like you ever change your `keys` map, so the player's `facingX` fields will _never_ change. Instead of trying to maintain state of key press/releases yourself, why not just poll the state of the keys directly with `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)`?

Comment: If you're going to have a whole bunch of booleans for facing, but never all the character to be facing more than one direction at a time, it'd be better just to have a Direction enum and get and set with that instead.  It'll make your code a lot easier to follow and spot your errors.

Comment: I keep getting an error with the drawPlayer() method in WorldRenderer, more specifically, with spriteBatch.draw(). Not sure why.